# I am looking for a regex that finds " } } {" this pattern for json object for correction in python

Tags: python, json, regex

Someones help will be really helpful. 
the json pattern looks something like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"]
  }
}
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"]
  }
}
```

Currently it is not in json format and i am trying to format it correctly so json.loads method can parse multiple objects.

So far I have got "}\r\n}"  and "*?(?=}\r\n})" and this does not work on my JSON file. It says no matches but i was able to verify what that regex means in an online validator.

Comment: Something like [**`}\s+{`**](https://regex101.com/r/5KBH46/1) ?

Comment: what is the intended output? the attributes repeat so do you want an array or.... ?

Comment: It looks like your data has an extra "}" and that's what you want to get rid of? Its still not json when you are done because the dicts are not enclosed in an outer container. Can you post example code so we can see how you call the regex?

Comment: Do you use the multiline flag? You could do `data = re.sub(r"}[\s\n]*}", "}", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: The bigger question is, what format is it? I showed you a fragile hack that could blow up if there are legit braces in there that match the same pattern.

Comment: I think `}[\r\n]+}` should do the trick.

Comment: I am using re.findall method and I apologize i am missing one of the opening braces on the top. the json format is { { [ ] } } { { [] } } multiple json objects  which i am putting them into list. So I am puttin all objects into a giant list , so i need to need  " , " between each objects.

Comment: I tried all suggestions but no luck, thank for suggestions though.

Comment: If you are reading several separate json streams, then want to output them all in a list then you don't want to descend to regexp hacking text. Best to convert all to python data, insert them in a list, then convert the list back to Json. Much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to match `}}{`

```
(?s)}[^{}]*\}[^{}]*{
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/94)

In python script,

```
ss=""" (copy & paste your text in this area)  """

regx= re.compile(r'(?s)}[^{}]*\}[^{}]*{')
print(regx.sub('SomethingYouWant',ss))    # replace all target strings to SomethingYouWant
```

Output is

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"]
  SomethingYouWant
  "type": "object",
  "properties": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It works on online but not with the python for some reason. Here is my function.cont = re.findall(r"(?s)}[^{}]*\}[^{}]*{", str(file.read()),flags=re.MULTILINE)

Comment: Could you pls upload a sample file?

Comment: And it must be implemented in `singleline`(`dot-all`) mode, not in `multiline` mode. please remove `flags=re.MULTILINE` in your script

Comment: As you can see, there is no matching in your sample text in above comment. pls upload another one.

Comment: This command works well, `re.findall(r"(?s)}[^{}]*\}[^{}]*{", ss)`

Comment: "ec2-unused-security-group": {
    "checked_items": 17,
    "dashboard_name": "",
    "description": "",
    "flagged_items": 0,
    "items": [
    ],
    "level": "warning",
    "path": "",
    "rationale": "N/A",
    "service": ""
  }
}
"ec2-unused-security-group": {
    "checked_items": 17,
    "dashboard_name": "",
    "description": "",
    "flagged_items": 0,
    "items": [
    ],
    "level": "warning",
    "path": "",
    "rationale": "N/A",
    "service": ""
  }
}

Comment: Seems like If i put it into  a string then it works but when i am reading it from file it does not work, any clue why?

Comment: Then could you pls uplad a file?. In edit mode this question, you could upload a file

Comment: Otherwise, upload a file to google or somewhere else and give me a download link

Comment: Thank you for your help,  I was able to read a file into a string and it works now. Appreciate it.

Comment: I did but it show up because i have less than 15 reputation so it will not show up thank you for your time.